# Carmichel Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p be a natural number.
why does $a^(p-1)\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$  for all a coprime to p implies $a^p\equiv a \pmod{p}$

for all natural numbers $a$.

This is stated in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply by $a$ on both sides of the congruence

Comment: but why a^p=a mod p for all naturals as in the hypotesis we have only the coprimes of a

Answer (score 4):

$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p \iff p \mid a^{p-1} - 1 \implies p \mid a(a^{p-1} - 1) \iff$$

$$ p  \mid a^p - a \iff a^p \equiv a \pmod p$$

Comment: but why a^p=a mod p for all naturals as in the hypotesis we have only the coprimes of p

Comment: @philip If a isn't coprime to p then , $p \mid a$ and hence the conclusion

Comment: p is not required to be a prime!

Comment: @Philip The Carmichael numbers are square free number, so we can decompose it into product of prime factors (distinct) then what I said is true for those primes and we can "glue" the results with the Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: I don't understand